# Apex update trigger - updating Detail Fields

Tags: apex, trigger, master-detail

I have a situation where I have a two objects called Premises and Location. I have a master detail relationship from Premises to Location. I want to write a trigger so that whenever a recored is changed on the Location, it would also reflect on the related Premises records. Im not quite sure how to approach this. Any help. thanks

PS: Premise is the detail record

This is what i've tried so far:

```
global override void MainEntry(List<SObject> newlist, Map<ID, SObject> newmap, List<SObject> oldlist, Map<ID,SObject> oldmap)
    {
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){

            executeUpdated((List<Location__c>)newList, oldmap);
        }
    }

    private void executeUpdated(List<Location__c> newlist, Map<ID, SObject> oldmap)
    {
        List<String> locationList = new List<String>();
        for (Location__c loc : newList)
        {
            locationList.add(loc.Id);
        }

        Map<Id, Premises> locMap = new Map<Id, Premises>([SELECT Id, Location__c FROM Premises__c WHERE Id =: locationList]);

        for (Location__c loc : newList)
        {
            Location__c lookUpObj = locMap.get(loc.Id);
            if (lookUpObj != null){}
            //obj.Master1 = lookup1_Object.Lookup2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is Location the Detail and Premises the Master? The Detail record will have a field with the Id of the Master you can use to update the Master. If the reverse, you'll need to query the Detail object using the Master Object record's Id to get those records. What issue are you having?

Comment: The Premises__c is the Detail. Could you please provide some code example @crmprogdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Use it if Child Record to be updated only under certain Field update on the parent

```
private void executeUpdated(){
List<String> locationList = new List<String>();

    for (Location__c newLoc : Trigger.new) {
        Location__c oldLoc = Trigger.oldMap.get(newLoc.Id);
        // To check if a Particular field has been updated
        if (newLoc.Fieldname != oldLoc.Fieldname) {
            locationList.add(newLoc.Id);
        }
    }
    List<Premises__c> listToUpdate = new List<Premises__c>();
    Premises__c premiseToUpdate = new Premises__c();
    Map<Id, Premises> locMap = new Map<Id, Premises>([SELECT Id, Location__c FROM Premises__c **WHERE Id IN: locationList**]);

        for (Location__c loc : locationList)
        {
            if (locMap.get(loc.Id) != null){
                // The Update 
                premiseToUpdate = locMap.get(loc.Id);
                premiseToUpdate.fieldToUpdate = <updated Value>;
                listToUpdate.add(premiseToUpdate);
            }
        }
        database.update(listToUpdate);
}
```

Refer: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/mass-updating-contacts-when-an-account-changes

Comment: Good try at this, but it won't work.  Your creation of the mapping like that won't work since Premise is a different object than location.  Also, even if that did work it would only update a single premise instead of all related ones.  You would need a Map<Id, List<Premise__c>> to do that.  If that was fixed though it could be a viable answer.

Comment: Premise is the detail record. @dphil could you pls provide some code example?

Comment: @ShashankShastri, when you post code, after pasting it into your post, please select it and click on the `{}` pre-formatted text icon so that it's legible to anyone who reads it. It's always a good practice to look at the preview pane of your post to fix any problems before posting it. Posts that are hard to read or understand are of little value as answers.

Comment: Map<Id, List<Premise__c>> premiseMap = new Map<Id, List<Premise__c>>();
for (Premise__c pre: [SELECT Id FROM Premise__c WHERE Location__c IN :locationList])
{List<Premise__c> prems = premiseMap.get(pre.Location__c);if(prems == null){prems = new List<Premise__c>();premiseMap.put(pre.Location__c, prems);}prems.add(pre);}

Comment: @dphil I have an error of : Illegal assignment from Premises__c to List<RS_Premises__c>. How do I convert the map into a List? thx

Comment: @codeSlayer You should have tried looking this up.  It's really easy to find:  **myMap.values();**

Answer (score 0):

I assume Premise is master and locaion is detail.In future you may want to define relationship clearly.I type from my phone so I am not able to format the code.hopefully this will help.

```
  trigger AfterPremisUpdate on Premise__c (after update) {  
   Set<Id> premisIds = new Set<Id>();
   Map<Id,Premise__c> mapPremise= new Map<Id,Premise__c>()
   for(Premise__c s : Trigger.new) { 
     premisIds.add(s.Id);
     mapPremise.put(s.Id,s);
   } 
   //Inside the same trigger or utility class , just get back the related Permission object with location id.

   List < Location__c> pList = [select id,whateverrelatedfield,Premise__c from Location__c where Premise__c in : premisIds. ];
   List < Location__c> updatelist =new List < Location__c>();
   for(Location__c p: pList){
      if(mapPremise.containskey(p.Premise__c){
         p. whateverrelatedfield = updatevalue;
         updatelist.add(p);
   }
   update updatelist;    
 }
```

Comment: When you post code, after pasting it into your post, please select it and click on the `{}` pre-formatted text icon so that it's legible to anyone who reads it. It's always a good practice to look at the preview pane of your post to fix any problems before posting it. Posts that are hard to read or understand are of little value as answers. This is not the first time I've edited one of your posts to make your code readable.

Comment: actually @unidha, the Premises__c is the Detail and Location is the Master. could you pls modify the code to. will mark answer your answer.. thx

Comment: actually @crmprogdev I could not see that {} in my mobilephone ,anyway I update the answer using my laptop.@codeSlayer I already updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, this is possible to do using the Process Builder as well. In this example, I created the Location object along with the child Premises object. Both objects have a lookup to the Account object. The process builder is set to trigger on the Location object "when a record is created or edited" and when the lookup "Account" field is changed. The immediate action is to take that Account value on Location and set it on all child Premises records.

[image]